# Adding Ctrl-Click "Go To Definition" support to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shortcut

Previously using Visual Studio 2013, I would use [the awesome extension from Noah Richards](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b) which would add Ctrl-Click as a shortcut for Go To Definition, but he hasnt updated the extension to be compatible with VS2015. And as far as I know, VS2015 doesnt provide any way to have this functionality by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So here's how I fixed this.

1. First download Noah Richard's extension from: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b
2. Save the .vsix file somewhere on your computer
3. Open the file with Winzip / Winrar or similar (it's just a disguised .zip file so you could change the extension to .zip)
4. Open the extension.vsixmanifest file in a text editor
5. Add the following lines inside the `<SupportedProducts>...</SupportedProducts>` section:

`<VisualStudio Version="14.0">
   <Edition>Pro</Edition>
</VisualStudio>`

6. Update the zip file with the modified file and change it back to a .vsix file.
7. Double click the .vsix and install.

Comment: I tried to install it using these instructions-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906944/visual-studio-does-not-install-vsix-files. Got an error that version is not supported. Looked at extension.vsixmanifest. It mentions only Pro versions of visual studio. I have 2012 express. What do I add to the manifest file to make it work ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 I'm guessing you can just use `<Edition>Express</Edition>` or something similar. You can also open another .vsix file to see what entries they have.

Comment: It's been updated (Nov 2015) since this answer, and now claims to work with VS2015 without modification.

Answer (score 12):

Install [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d).

Comment: Productivity Power Tools 2015's default configuration is for Ctrl-click to Peek Definition.  If you want it to Go To Definition instead, go to Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Other Extensions, and uncheck Ctrl Click shows definitions in Peek

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Microsoft [ctrl+click go to definition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.CtrlClickGoToDefinition) extension tool

Comment: For the link you provided, they made a note which I think is necessary for us to know **Note: This extension is only supported up to Visual Studio 2017.......** .

Comment: My mistake not including that the author's comment about support. After that version, the "ctrl+click go to definition" feature is included by default in Visual Studio.