# Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows - Report designer missing

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio **Express** 2015 for Windows Desktop - ENU and SQL Server Data Tools. In Control panel I don't see the screen as with Enterprise Edition to activate SQL Server Data Tools. The Window looks like this:

[No possibility to select SQL Data Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZI0e.png)

I also tried to install Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio but got a error message:

[Report designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX7sU.png)

I received a few Reports for a Program that runs in german language and need to translate them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not use Visual Studio Community 2017 instead?

Comment: if I remember well, the .vsix is a .zip file - so you can open it with say 7-zip (drag-drop it in 7-zip or rename to .vsix.zip first) and checkout the manifest file in it that specifies the versions of Visual Studio it is meant for

Comment: Will Visual Studio Community open the rldc files made with Version 2015? I opened the zip file and there was no manifest file to open in order to see what it is meant for.

Comment: you should check the Visual Studio Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com - can also find and install extensions from inside Visual Studio, see the menus), on whether there's a version of Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer that you mention and for which Visual Studio versions it is available

Comment: regarding the manifest in the .vsix file see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/08/08/update-for-extension-authors-vsix-manifest-version-range-attribute/

Comment: also, in cases where the VSIX installation system is broken one should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906944/visual-studio-does-not-install-vsix-files - but in your case it seems you've either not first installed Visual Studio (before running the .vsix), or you have wrong version of Visual Studio (not one that your .vsix supports)

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio 2017 Community edition for free (or higher, e.g. if you have MSDN subscription) - see terms though, community edition isn't for the enterprise - from:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Then get the Rdlc Report Designer extension from:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

or from inside Visual Studio ("Tools/Extensions and Updates" menu if I remember well)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your advice. In installed them both and they work just fine. The only problem I have is that the software I use for report output doesn't work with reports created/modified with version 2017 (only 2008 and 2015). So I am still at the beginning.

Comment: You can still download older Visual Studio Express and Community versions, VS 2015 Community is available from Microsoft for free at https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads. So you then need to find the VS2015 extension for report designer. Probably the easiest way to do it is to use the Extensions & Updates dialog (from the Tools menu) from inside Visual Studio and go to the Online category there and then enter "Rdlc" as search term.

Comment: I installed the VS 2015 Community, but unfortunatelly there ist no RDLC Report Designer found, eather in Marketplace (only for 2017 is found) or within Extensions & Updates. Everywhere I looked on the Web, there are sollutions only for Enterprise Edition.

Comment: As I just found out is there no possibility to edit RLDC Files with free version of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: :-( so, only if the program you use gets some update to be compatible with newer RDLC or you happen to find some converter to the older format

Comment: Yes, or if I buy the Enterprise version to translate 4 reports I need, but I won't do that. Fortunatelly I can use old reports for the software I use.